# underscore _.union not removing duplicates for dates arrays using bookshelf

Tags: underscore.js

I'm wondering why in underscore (using bookshelf as well) if we use _.union for dates array, the duplicates are not being removed.

For example:

```
var union = _.union ( model.get( 'dates' ), [ new Date( date ) ] );
```

Where model.get( 'dates' ) it's a date array in Postgres database.

This doesn't remove the duplicate dates.

Thanks in advance. Guillermo.

Comment: Dates are objects, and those are compared by reference. Your `new Date` will never equal anything contained in the other array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up to @Bergi's insightful comment:

> Dates are objects, and those are compared by reference. Your new Date will never equal anything contained in the other array.

You can make this work by storing your date objects as UNIX timestamps (which are just numbers), using `new Date( date ).getTime()`. You may have to do this for your model's `dates` array when you pull it from the DB as well as the date you are adding to the array.

Here's a quick snippet illustrating this:

```js
var model = new Backbone.Model();

model.set('dates', [1424723679080]);

var union = _.union(model.get('dates'), [ new Date().getTime() ]);

console.log('test1');

if (union.length === 2) {
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'test1 passed. ';
    console.log(union);
} else {
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'test1 failed. ';
    console.log(union);
}

union = _.union(model.get('dates'), [1424723679080]);

console.log('test2');

if (union.length === 1) {
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML += 'test2 passed. ';
    console.log(union);
} else {
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML += 'test2 failed. ';
    console.log(union);
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min.js"></script>

<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Is it [1424723679080] needed to convert the date to timestamp?

Comment: No, sorry; that's just test data. That number is a Unix timestamp (a Unix timestamp is the number of milliseconds from a specific date in 1970 or so that I can't remember.) If you look at the data in a debugger, that's what your dates will look like after you convert them to timestamps.

Comment: ...Aaand the date I couldn't remember would be January 1st in UTC. Now you can see how non-memorable it is. :P